# Reading file in Java language

Tags: java, audio, arrays, filenotfoundexception, javasound

Hello I am having trouble reading a file in Java into a bytearray. Can someone help me with properly reading the file as I am getting errors including "The system cannot find the file specified" thought I have saved the file in the src folder.

Comment: I gotta ask - try/finally? where's the catch? :)

Comment: If it's complaining that it can't find the file are you sure the file is there? have you tried an absolute path?

Comment: @Shark: A catch block is not required, nor is it incorrect to omit it.

Comment: Try putting a `System.out` with the value of `myFile.isFile()`. If it is false then you know the problem is with the path, otherwise with the library.

Comment: I added System.out.println(myFile.isFile()); but once I try to run all I get is 'Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: H:\auSample.au (The system cannot find the file specified)' on the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't provide a full path, the filename you specify will be relative to the *working directory* of your program.

> By default the classes in the java.io package always resolve relative pathnames against the current user directory. This directory is named by the system property user.dir, and is typically the directory in which the Java virtual machine was invoked. - [**File javadoc**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String%29)

It is therefore dependent on how you launch your code.  Either use an absolute path, or put the file in the correct directory.

Typically if the file you want to read is to be distributed with your code, you instead want to use Java's resource capabilities instead of interacting with the filesystem by putting the file in the classpath and loading it with `ClassLoader.getResource()`.

Comment: Hello, I am sure I have the file in the correct directory. Would the problem be the code I have is incorrect?

Comment: *"I am sure I have the file in the correct directory"*  I'm sure you don't.  Call `System.out.println(myFile.exists());` to prove me wrong.

Comment: I still get this "Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: auSample.au (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.media.sound.WaveFloatFileReader.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
 at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
 at wave.main(wave.java:18)"

Comment: @OasisTea: Then it appears you haven't fixed the problem.  You haven't demonstrated that you've tried any of the suggestions I've given, so I'm not inclined to give *more* suggestions yet.

Comment: Hello, I was using ClassLoader.getResource(); incorrectly before. I received some help with it and now it is working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Applet AudioClip api:

http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/applet/ui/sound.html

```
 AudioCLip clip=Applet.newAudioClip(wave.class.getResource("auSample.au"));
 clip.play();
```

if the clip is in the same package as the class. If it is instead on the root, use:

```
  AudioCLip clip=Applet.newAudioClip(wave.class.getResource("/auSample.au"));
```

Comment: 1) Java Sound has been in the J2SE since Java 1.3 (no need for the applet based `AudioClip`) 2)  This has everything to do with paths, and little if nothing to do with the sound itself.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this command:

```
File fin = new File("111.txt");
FileInputStream fin1 = new FileInputStream(fin);
BufferedInputStream f =new BufferedInputStream(fin1);
```

Note: if you want to call your file, your file has to be in your package